# How to achieve MVVM like frameworks in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mvvm

I have a simple problem. I think, I misunderstand the ReactJS usage.

I want to author some low level **reusable components** to build my forms in a standard layout.

Consider something like this.

```
    var Note = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return ActionData.Model; //the form model
    },

    render: function () {
        var model = this.state;
        return (
            <Fieldset id="testId" Legend={Language.Note}>
                <SingleColumn Lable="Note">
                    <Textarea value={model.Text} />
                </SingleColumn>
                <TwinColumn RightLable="Date" LeftLable="">
                    <DatePicker ReadOnly="true" Date={model.DisplayDate} />
                    <Checkbox Title="show " />
                </TwinColumn>
                <input type="button" value="Save" onClick={this.save} />
            </Fieldset>
            )
    },

    save: function () {
        var model = this.state;
        //save the model here ... .
    }
});

$(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<Note />, $("#myContent")[0]);
})
```

And for instance in 'Textarea' component

```
    var Textarea = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            value: this.props.value
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        return <input type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.value} onChange={e => this.setState({value: e.target.value})} />
    }
});
```

How can I update the 'Note' component state on 'Textarea' change state? (performing something like MVVM frameworks).

Am I walking in the correct direction?!

Is ReactJs capable of doing such things !?

Comment: You could have look at: https://medium.com/react-weekly/building-a-react-mobx-application-with-mvvm-ec0b3e3c8786#.k4qmh3k9l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a function from your Note component to the Textarea component via props:

```
<Textarea value={model.Text} onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({ value })} />
```

In this way your child component `Textarea` simply can simply call the passed `onValueChange` function:

```
return (
  <input type="text" className="form-control"
  value={this.state.value} 
  onChange={e => this.props.onValueChange(e.target.value)} />
);
```